# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, terminal

I know this question is asked many times, and I read al lot of questions going about this, but I think mine is different.

I use a Mac with version 10.10.3 and a Terminal to do my commands.

I am trying to create a local database (and I did it before), but for some reason the access is constantly denied.

**This is how my terminal looks like:**

```
iMac-van:mysql 639$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Reading history-file /Users/639/.mysql_history
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> quit;
Writing history-file /Users/639/.mysql_history
Bye
iMac-van:mysql 639$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> create database wordpress_db;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'wordpress_db'
```

As you can see I can login to mysql, but I have no permission to create a database.

I tried to login like:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

And:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

I have no password, but I can enter mysql without one, but then I cannot create a database.

Select current_user(); returns this:

```
mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to start mysql with --skip-grant-tables

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

then connect to your mysqld without username/password using mysql command line

```
shell> mysql
```

then issue command

```
> mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
>        WHERE User='root'; mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did the mysqld, connected to mysql did the command but didn't work.. ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user

Comment: Since there is no `mysqld` binary on my system, I had to add `skip-grant-tables` to `/etc/my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` and run `service mysqld restart` to enable it

Answer (score 0):

First, try this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

but replace 5.5 with your current mysql-server version, and you will be asked for the new root password.

If that doesn't work, try [these instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html%23resetting-permissions-unix) from the manual.

Comment: I have reinstalled mysql and this worked for me. Thanks for your answer. I cannot try it now, but will keep it in mind it the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
All I had to do was to log out of the shell and log in again using `mysql -u root -p` into my mysql shell.

This will then prompt for a password.
Since I didn't use a password while setting up, I pressed enter and that was it for me.

I hope this works for you too :) .